# Accuracy very different from CV

Tags: cross-validation, random-forest, scikit-learn, accuracy, model-evaluation

In my random forest classifier in Python (2 classes), I am getting an accuracy score of 46.9 % (using accuracy_score from sklearn.metrics).

However, when I print clf.cv_results_['mean_test_score'], all ten results are above 65%.

What's going on? Is there a bug? My apologies if this is a simple question.

Comment: When scoring only 46.9% accuracy, on what data is this being computed? Train data or a test set? If the latter, how did you split the data? Are there classes equally frequent throughout your data?

Comment: This 46.9% accuracy is being computed from the test set. It is split with the train_test_split function in sklearn, and yes, there are 200 examples of one class and 200 examples of the other class.

Answer (score 2):

> However, when I print clf.cv_results_['mean_test_score'], all ten
>   results are above 65%.

Did you have a look at the standard deviation of the scored accuracy during CV? That deviation might explain your observed result on the other train-test split. Furthermore you have to consider, that the composition of the sets in your train-test split is different than in your tenfold CV due to the difference in set size.

If you want to investigate this further you can perform such train-test splitting several times with different random states/seeds and have a look at the test accuracy on these, as well as their dispersion.